# Do multiple e-mail addresses need to be separated by a comma?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, csv

In CSV format, in an Excel spreadsheet or in a Word document, both having multiple email addresses with each address being in its own row and in a single column, is a comma REQUIRED after each address?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to that is entirely dependent on what you are going to do with those email addresses.  Email addresses in a word document, or in excel, or in whatever, can be separated by whatever you feel like - whatever is most pleasing to the eye.

> fred@bloggs.com :) foo@bar.com :) mail@example.com

is just one example of email addresses separated by smilies.

The only one you mentioned that has any strict formatting is the CSV file, where fields are separated by a column.  If the email addresses are grouped into one column then if I were you I'd separate them with anything *except* commas.

So until we know what you are going to do with the email addresses we can't tell you what is required to delimit them.

Comment: Do frowns make Excel sad?

Comment: No, they make it crash :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to use the e-mail addresses as the recipient list for your e-mails, you should be able to separate them with semi-colons. If you separate them with commas they'll be treated as separate columns by what ever reads the CSV file.

Though I'd double check that your e-mail client accepts that format first.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes should work within a CSV to keep a cell intact if you want to put commas in it.

Example:

```
Cell 1, Cell 2, "Cell 3, Still Cell 3", Cell 4
```